# Return true or false based on whether there are duplicates

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

When I have duplicates in my collection, I want to return true, otherwise, I want to return false.

I've got the following linq query.

```
var t = from i in selectedDrivers
        group i by i.Value into g
        where g.Count() > 1
        select g.Count() > 1;
```

Problem is though, that when there are multiple duplicates, it will return multiple trues, and if there aren't any duplicates, it returns nothing (should be false).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Problem is though, that when there are multiple duplicates, it will return multiple trues, and if there aren't any duplicates, it returns nothing (should be false).

Well that's easy to solve:

```
bool hasDupes = t.Any();
```

If there are multiple trues, that'll be true. If there are none, it'll be false.

But frankly, I would be inclined to simply write my own extension method that bails when it finds the *first* duplicate, rather than building up a set of all the duplicates and then querying that set:

```
static bool HasDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    var set = new HashSet<T>();
    foreach(T item in sequence)
    {
        if (set.Contains(item))
            return true;
        set.Add(item);
    }
    return false;
}
```

And now just say

```
bool dupes = selectedDrivers.HasDuplicates();
```

Easy peasy.

Comment: This was something that I forget to add - when it finds a duplicate, that should be enough and return. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Maybe one question? I see you have used a HashSet. Started to read about it and wondered why you used it?

Comment: @Garth: HashSets have the nice property that it is extremely fast to insert a new item and extremely fast to check to see if an item exists. In this case I'm using the set as a record of "everything I've seen already", and the two operations I need to be fast are precisely those: insert a new item, or tell me if an item is already there.

Comment: One possible optimization in your extension method is using the fact that `Add` returns if there was already in the set, allowing you to leave out the `Contains` call. But on the other hand that change reduces the readability. `if(!set.Add(item))return true;`

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Excellent point. I generally dislike expressions that are useful for both their side effects and their value, but there could be a real performance win here in the case where the collection is large and has no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
var t = (from i in selectedDrivers
    group i by i.Value into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select g.Count() > 1).Any();
```

I BELIEVE this will do the trick.

Comment: Close, but no cigar ;-) When I have no duplicates, it will still return true. I would like it to be false.

Comment: Interesting - .Any() is supposed to return true only if there are records.  Oh - I wonder... remove the last > 1 - I just realized it's evaluating the last bit as a boolean, so even if there are 0 records returned, 0>1 = false and false is a result so Any = true.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate your results in an or.

```
var q=from i in selectedDrivers
    group i by i.Value into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select g.Count() > 1

return q.Aggregate(false,(x,y)=>x|y);
```

Comment: Thanks. It's incredibly ineficient though.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most optomised solution, but....

```
var t = selectedDrivers.Distinct().Count() != selectedDrivers.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.

```
var t = selectedDrivers
    .GroupBy(item => item.Value)
    .Any(group => group.Skip(1).Any());
```

I have used 'group.Skip(1).Any()' to find a group with at least two elements and avoid enumerating the entire group with Count().

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as good as Eric's solution, because it will group the entire enumeration, but this seems like the right way to use `Any` here.

```
var t = selectedDrivers
    .GroupBy(item => item.Value)
    .Any(group => group.Count() > 1)
```